# lightbox2 image gallery doesnt work at all

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, lightbox, lightbox2

I followed this Lokesh Dhakar's guide how to create slide show image gallery:
https://www.lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/#options
and it still doesnt work for me and instead of a working gallery it just opens the images like basic link. I cant find anything useful on his page nor stackoverflow troubleshooting threads because I've read some solutions from other people but none worked for me. Any tips please?

Thanks for any help in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head style="background-color:powderblue;">
<title>Title</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/lightbox_custom.css">
</head>

<body>
<div>
    <a class="example-image-link" href="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/images/image-3.jpg" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="Click the right half of the image to move forward."><img class="example-image" src="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/images/thumb-3.jpg" alt=""/></a>
    <a class="example-image-link" href="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/images/image-4.jpg" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="Or press the right arrow on your keyboard."><img class="example-image" src="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/images/thumb-4.jpg" alt="" /></a>
    <a class="example-image-link" href="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/images/image-5.jpg" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="The next image in the set is preloaded as you're viewing."><img class="example-image" src="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/images/thumb-5.jpg" alt="" /></a>
    <a class="example-image-link" href="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/images/image-6.jpg" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="Click anywhere outside the image or the X to the right to close."><img class="example-image" src="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/images/thumb-6.jpg" alt="" /></a>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/lightbox.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Alright thanks for your help. After even more troubleshooting I finally found my mistake. 
Near the end I had:
`<script src="/js/lightbox.js"></script>`
instead of `<script src="js/lightbox.js"></script>`

That extra slash (**"/"**) in front of js/lightbox.js created all the problems and I didnt know I cant write it there due to my inexperience. It looks solved now.

Answer (score 0):

Using the links to the `lightbox` `CSS/JS` files from the `lightbox URL` you have posted (https://www.lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/), your posted code works. What does your `lightbox_custom.css` code look like? Are you using that file to overwrite the `lightbox.css` file? Have you modified the `lightbox.js` code?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head style="background-color:powderblue;">
  <title>Title</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/css/lightbox.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <a class="example-image-link" href="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/images/image-3.jpg" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="Click the right half of the image to move forward."><img class="example-image" src="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/images/thumb-3.jpg" alt="" /></a>
    <a class="example-image-link" href="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/images/image-4.jpg" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="Or press the right arrow on your keyboard."><img class="example-image" src="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/images/thumb-4.jpg" alt="" /></a>
    <a class="example-image-link" href="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/images/image-5.jpg" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="The next image in the set is preloaded as you're viewing."><img class="example-image" src="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/images/thumb-5.jpg" alt="" /></a>
    <a class="example-image-link" href="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/images/image-6.jpg" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="Click anywhere outside the image or the X to the right to close."><img class="example-image" src="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/images/thumb-6.jpg" alt="" /></a>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/js/lightbox-plus-jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: First thanks for your answer and the lightbox custom is only my css file merged with lightbox one because at first it looked like this: 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">  
 <link href="css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet">

but it didnt work so I figured maybe I can open only one css file so I merged them into one file and still nothing helped and no I didnt touch the lightbox.js file.

Comment: oh and now I tried using only: <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/css/lightbox.css">
 like you posted without my css styles and it still doesnt work